# Validação de Form com JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sou iniciante em *jQuery* e estou com dificuldade em fazer uma validação de formulário com *jQuery* para o **CRM** de uma igreja que é o seguinte:

Tenho um código *HTML* que faz parte de um **CRM** que eu estou desenvolvendo. Nesse *HTML* eu tenho um formulário com apenas uma linha e várias colunas, porém, existe a opção de adicionar mais linhas com o botão que fica logo ao lado das colunas. Até esse ponto, tudo OK.

O problema acontece na hora em que eu vou fazer a validação desses campos para poder gerar um arquivo *bean* do próprio **CRM** seguindo os passos para que a validação dê certo. Aconteceria da seguinte forma:

- Validar se o primeiro campo do *form* está preenchido (pois esse
  possui um `id`). Caso estiver, ele segue percorrendo as demais
  colunas e salvando em algum array ou coisa do tipo em *jQuery*.
- Se houver mais linhas, ele seguirá para a próxima linha e repetirá o
  processo (fiz um `foreach`, mas não sei se está certo) e esse
  processo vai acontecer até a última linha, onde, caso a última linha
  estiver totalmente sem preenchimento, ela será ignorada e será gerado
  o *bean* depois.
- A outra validação é que se no meio do `form` a primeira coluna, em
  qualquer linha, que estiver vazia, ele irá emitir uma mensagem de
  erro dizendo que o campo é obrigatório.

Abaixo vou deixar o código que fiz até o momento para ficar melhor o entendimento:

```js
function addRow(element) {
    var ln = $('#countLine').val();    
    ln++;
    
    $linha = $('#tabela tr:last').clone();
    $('input', $linha).val('');
    $('div.yui-ac-container', $linha).attr('id', 'EditView_Membro_results' + ln);
    $('ul.list-data', $linha).attr('id', 'UserAutoCompleteContent' + ln);
    
    $('.membro_id', $linha).attr('id', 'membro_id' + ln);
    $('.dizimo_id', $linha).attr('id', 'dizimo_id' + ln);
    $('.oferta_id', $linha).attr('id', 'oferta_id' + ln);
    $('.oferta_especial_id', $linha).attr('id', 'oferta_especial_id' + ln);
    $('.missoes_id', $linha).attr('id', 'missoes_id' + ln);
    $('.cesta_basica_id', $linha).attr('id', 'cesta_basica_id' + ln);
    $('.ana_nazareno_id', $linha).attr('id', 'ana_nazareno_id' + ln);
    $('.outros_id', $linha).attr('id', 'outros_id' + ln);
    
    $('.membro_autocomplete', $linha).attr('id', 'Membro' + ln);
    $('.dizimo_autocomplete', $linha).attr('id', 'Dizimo' + ln);
    $('.oferta_autocomplete', $linha).attr('id', 'Oferta' + ln);
    $('.oferta_especial_autocomplete', $linha).attr('id', 'OfertaEspecial' + ln);
    $('.missoes_autocomplete', $linha).attr('id', 'Missoes' + ln);
    $('.cesta_basica_autocomplete', $linha).attr('id', 'CestaBasica' + ln);
    $('.ana_nazareno_autocomplete', $linha).attr('id', 'AnaNazareno' + ln);
    $('.outros_autocomplete', $linha).attr('id', 'Outros' + ln);
    
    $('#tabela tr:last').after($linha);
    bind();
    
    $(element).attr('onclick', 'DeleteRow(this)');
    $(element).html('Remover');
    
    $('#countLine').val(ln);
}

function DeleteRow(element)
{
    var row = $(element).closest('tr');
    row.remove();
}
      
//adiciona classe css quando for feito o click
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("td").addClass("tabe");
    });
});

function HideDivsOnBlur()
{    
    $(".yui-ac-content").hide();
    $(".yui-ac-hd").hide();
}

function autoCompleteMembro(nomeMembro, idInput, divResults)
{
 var parametro = $(nomeMembro).val();
 var id_input = nomeMembro.attr('id');
 var row = id_input.match(/\d+/)[0];
 
 var dados = new Object();
 dados.form = "EditView";
 dados.method = "query";
 dados.modules = ["Accounts"];
 dados.field_list = ["name", "id"];
 dados.populate_list = ["account_name", "account_id_c"]; 
 dados.required_list = ["account_id_c"];
 dados.conditions = [{"name" : "name", "op" : "like_custom", "end" : "%", "value" : ""}];
 dados.limit = "10";
 dados.no_match_text = "Nada foi Encontrado";
 
 var dadosJson = JSON.stringify(dados);

 var dataJson = { to_pdf : "true", module : "Home", action : "quicksearchQuery", data : dadosJson, query : parametro}
 $.ajax({
 url: "index.php",
 data: dataJson,
 type: "post",        
 success: function(resp){
  console.log(resp);
  var resposta = $.parseJSON(resp);
  if(resposta.fields.length > 0)
  {
   // remove a lista buscada apos selecionar o membro
   $("#UserAutoCompleteContent"+ row + " li").remove();
   
   $("#EditView_Membro_results"+ row + " .yui-ac-content").show();
   $("#EditView_Membro_results"+ row + " .yui-ac-hd").show();
                        
   $(divResults).show();
   $(divResults).children(0).show();
   $(divResults).children(0).css("z-index", "10000");
   $(divResults).children(1).show();
   
   $(resposta.fields).each(function(index, item){
                        $("#UserAutoCompleteContent"+row).append(
                                '<li style="z-index: 10000;" onclick="changeAssignedUserId(\'' 
                                + item.id + '\', \'' + item.name.toUpperCase() + '\',\'' + $(idInput).attr('id') + '\',\'' + 
                                $(nomeMembro).attr('id') + '\',\'' + $(divResults).find('ul').attr('id') + '\');">' 
                                + item.name.toUpperCase() + '</li>');
                        
   });
   $("#EditView_Membro_results"+row+" li").hover( 
                function(){ 
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#426FD9")
                    $(this).css("color", "#fff")
                },
                function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#fff")
                    $(this).css("color", "#000")
                });
            } 
        }
    });
}

function changeAssignedUserId(Id, Name, MembroIdInputId, ProdNomeInputId, UlId)
{
    console.log(MembroIdInputId);
    $("#" + MembroIdInputId).val(Id);
    $("#" + ProdNomeInputId).val(Name);
    
    // remove a lista buscada apos selecionar o item
    $("#" + UlId + " li").remove();
    
    // esconde o bloco do resultado da busca
    $(".yui-ac-content").hide();
    $(".yui-ac-hd").hide();
}

function bind()
{
    $('.membro_autocomplete').unbind('keyup').keyup(function(){ 
 $inputMembro = $(this).closest('input');
 $inputMembroId = $(this).closest('td').find("input[class='membro_id']"); 
 $divResultados = $(this).closest('td').find("input[class='yui-ac-container']"); 
  
 autoCompleteMembro($inputMembro, $inputMembroId, $divResultados);
    }); 
}
bind();

function sendToPhp()
{
    /* Verificar validação */
    var linha  = [];
    $('#tabela tr').each(function(){
        
        $(this).find("input[type=text]").each(function() {
//            if($('#Membro0').val() !== ''){
////                $('#Membro0').closest("td");
//                console.log($('#Membro0').val());
//                return true;
//            }
//            else{
//                console.log('Chegou aqui Valor Nulo');
//                return false;
//            }
            linha = [ $(this).val() ];
            console.log(linha)
        });
        
        // loop no array linha
        
        
    });
//        if($('.membro_id').val() !== null)
//        {
//            //foreach verificando se o proximo de cada posição na coluna possui valor
//            //setar com false e em caso de valor mudar para true
//        }
//        else if($('.membro_id').val() === null)
//        {
//            //foreach verificando se o proximo de cada posição na coluna possui valor
//            //setar com false e em caso de valor mudar para true
//        }
}

function check()
{
    var ok = 1;
    $('#Membro0').blur(function()
        {
            if($(this).val().length === 0)
            { 
                ok = 0; $(this).css('border-color','red');
                alert('Campo MEMBRO deve ser preenchido');
            }
    else{ $(this).css('border-color',''); }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="EditView_tabs"> 
    <div>
        <div id="detailpanel_1" class="edit view edit508  expanded">            
            
            <form id="formRelatorio" method="POST" action="index.php?module=culto_relatorio_dizimo&action=gravaRelatorio">
                <input type="hidden" name="module" value="culto_relatorio_dizimo">
                <input type="hidden" name="record" value="">
                <input type="hidden" id="action" name="gravaRelatorio">
                <input type="hidden" name="return_module" value="culto_relatorio_dizimo">
                <input type="hidden" name="return_action" value="relatorioDizimo">
                
                <table id="tabela"  width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" class="yui3-skin-sam edit view panelContainer">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="larg">Membro</th>
                        <th class="larg">Dizimo</th>
                        <th class="larg">Oferta</th>
                        <th class="larg">Oferta Especial</th>
                        <th class="larg">Missões</th>
                        <th class="larg">Cesta Básica</th>
                        <th class="larg">ANA Nazareno</th>
                        <th class="larg">Outros</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class='conteudo'>
                        
                        <td class="tabe"> 
                           <input id="membro_id0" class="membro_id" type="hidden" value="">
                           <input id="Membro0" class="larg membro_autocomplete" type="text">                            
                           <div id="EditView_Membro_results0" class="yui-ac-container">
                               <div class="yui-ac-content" style="display: none;">
                                   <div class="yui-ac-hd" style="display: none;">
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="yui-ac-bd">
                                       <ul id="UserAutoCompleteContent0" style="z-index: 100;" class='list-data'> </ul>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="yui-ac-ft" style="display: none;">
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="tabe"> 
                            <input id="dizimo_id0" class="dizimo_id" type="hidden" value="">
                            <input id="Dizimo0" class="larg dizimo_autocomplete" type="text"> 
                            <div id="EditView_Dizimo_results0" class="yui-ac-container">
                              
                           </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="tabe"> 
                            <input id="oferta_id0" class="oferta_id" type="hidden" value="">
                            <input id="Oferta0" class="larg oferta_autocomplete" type="text"> 
                            <div id="EditView_Oferta_results0" class="yui-ac-container">
                              
                           </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="tabe"> 
                            <input id="oferta_especial_id0" class="oferta_especial_id" type="hidden" value="">
                            <input id="OfertaEspecial0" class="larg oferta_especial_autocomplete" type="text"> 
                            <div id="EditView_OfertaEspecial_results0" class="yui-ac-container">
                              
                           </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="tabe"> 
                            <input id="missoes_id0" class="missoes_id" type="hidden" value="">
                            <input id="Missoes0" class="larg missoes_autocomplete" type="text"> 
                            <div id="EditView_Missoes_results0" class="yui-ac-container">
                              
                           </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="tabe"> 
                            <input id="cesta_basica_id0" class="cesta_basica_id" type="hidden" value="">
                            <input id="CestaBasica0" class="larg cesta_basica_autocomplete" type="text"> 
                            <div id="EditView_CestaBasica_results0" class="yui-ac-container">
                              
                           </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="tabe"> 
                            <input id="ana_nazareno_id0" class="ana_nazareno_id" type="hidden" value="">
                            <input id="AnaNazareno0" class="larg ana_nazareno_autocomplete" type="text"> 
                            <div id="EditView_AnaNazareno_results0" class="yui-ac-container">
                              
                           </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="tabe"> 
                            <input id="outros_id0" class="outros_id" type="hidden" value="">
                            <input id="Outros0" class="larg outros_autocomplete" type="text"> 
                            <div id="EditView_Outros_results0" class="yui-ac-container">
                              
                           </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td> <button type="button" onclick="addRow(this)">Adicionar</button> </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </form>
            
            <div class="fora">
                <button type="button" class="buton" id="sendBtnEnviar" onclick="sendToPhp()">Inserir</button> 
                <input id="countLine" class="countLine" type="hidden" value="1"> 
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O famoso `console.log()` traz algum resultado?

Comment: sim ele traz o nome do membro no primeiro campo

Comment: Sobre a função que você usa ao clicar o botão de envio (claro, isso não é usado, sendo que no próprio jQuery pode capturar o evento do botão [como você é iniciante, é bom dar uma olhada]), onde você declarou a variável `$linha` ?

Comment: verei isso sim, a variável $linha esta declarada logo no inicio da function addRow

Comment: Para os campos obrigatórios você pode usar o "required" do HTML5. Para percorrer os campos e validar os valores, pode usar o .each() do jQuery:

$( "#tabela input" ).each(function( ) {
  var texto = $.trim($(this).val());
});

trim remove os espaços em branco no início e fim.

Comment: Para a validação, achei isso aqui (ainda não testei): https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: @user53602 qual nome da igreja? Ainda precisa de ajuda ?

Answer (score 1):

Segue a validação com resultado final em JSON `jsonResultado`:

```js
function addRow(element) {
    var ln = $('#countLine').val();    
    ln++;
    
    $linha = $('#tabela tr:last').clone();
    $('input', $linha).val('');
    $('div.yui-ac-container', $linha).attr('id', 'EditView_Membro_results' + ln);
    $('ul.list-data', $linha).attr('id', 'UserAutoCompleteContent' + ln);
    
    $('.membro_id', $linha).attr('id', 'membro_id' + ln);
    $('.dizimo_id', $linha).attr('id', 'dizimo_id' + ln);
    $('.oferta_id', $linha).attr('id', 'oferta_id' + ln);
    $('.oferta_especial_id', $linha).attr('id', 'oferta_especial_id' + ln);
    $('.missoes_id', $linha).attr('id', 'missoes_id' + ln);
    $('.cesta_basica_id', $linha).attr('id', 'cesta_basica_id' + ln);
    $('.ana_nazareno_id', $linha).attr('id', 'ana_nazareno_id' + ln);
    $('.outros_id', $linha).attr('id', 'outros_id' + ln);
    
    $('.membro_autocomplete', $linha).attr('id', 'Membro' + ln);
    $('.dizimo_autocomplete', $linha).attr('id', 'Dizimo' + ln);
    $('.oferta_autocomplete', $linha).attr('id', 'Oferta' + ln);
    $('.oferta_especial_autocomplete', $linha).attr('id', 'OfertaEspecial' + ln);
    $('.missoes_autocomplete', $linha).attr('id', 'Missoes' + ln);
    $('.cesta_basica_autocomplete', $linha).attr('id', 'CestaBasica' + ln);
    $('.ana_nazareno_autocomplete', $linha).attr('id', 'AnaNazareno' + ln);
    $('.outros_autocomplete', $linha).attr('id', 'Outros' + ln);
    
    $('#tabela tr:last').after($linha);
    bind();
    
    $(element).attr('onclick', 'DeleteRow(this)');
    $(element).html('Remover');
    
    $('#countLine').val(ln);
}

function DeleteRow(element)
{
    var row = $(element).closest('tr');
    row.remove();
}
      
//adiciona classe css quando for feito o click
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("td").addClass("tabe");
    });
});

function HideDivsOnBlur()
{    
    $(".yui-ac-content").hide();
    $(".yui-ac-hd").hide();
}

function autoCompleteMembro(nomeMembro, idInput, divResults)
{
 var parametro = $(nomeMembro).val();
 var id_input = nomeMembro.attr('id');
 var row = id_input.match(/\d+/)[0];
 
 var dados = new Object();
 dados.form = "EditView";
 dados.method = "query";
 dados.modules = ["Accounts"];
 dados.field_list = ["name", "id"];
 dados.populate_list = ["account_name", "account_id_c"]; 
 dados.required_list = ["account_id_c"];
 dados.conditions = [{"name" : "name", "op" : "like_custom", "end" : "%", "value" : ""}];
 dados.limit = "10";
 dados.no_match_text = "Nada foi Encontrado";
 
 var dadosJson = JSON.stringify(dados);

 var dataJson = { to_pdf : "true", module : "Home", action : "quicksearchQuery", data : dadosJson, query : parametro}
 $.ajax({
 url: "index.php",
 data: dataJson,
 type: "post",        
 success: function(resp){
  console.log(resp);
  var resposta = $.parseJSON(resp);
  if(resposta.fields.length > 0)
  {
   // remove a lista buscada apos selecionar o membro
   $("#UserAutoCompleteContent"+ row + " li").remove();
   
   $("#EditView_Membro_results"+ row + " .yui-ac-content").show();
   $("#EditView_Membro_results"+ row + " .yui-ac-hd").show();
                        
   $(divResults).show();
   $(divResults).children(0).show();
   $(divResults).children(0).css("z-index", "10000");
   $(divResults).children(1).show();
   
   $(resposta.fields).each(function(index, item){
                        $("#UserAutoCompleteContent"+row).append(
                                '<li style="z-index: 10000;" onclick="changeAssignedUserId(\'' 
                                + item.id + '\', \'' + item.name.toUpperCase() + '\',\'' + $(idInput).attr('id') + '\',\'' + 
                                $(nomeMembro).attr('id') + '\',\'' + $(divResults).find('ul').attr('id') + '\');">' 
                                + item.name.toUpperCase() + '</li>');
                        
   });
   $("#EditView_Membro_results"+row+" li").hover( 
                function(){ 
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#426FD9")
                    $(this).css("color", "#fff")
                },
                function(){
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#fff")
                    $(this).css("color", "#000")
                });
            } 
        }
    });
}

function changeAssignedUserId(Id, Name, MembroIdInputId, ProdNomeInputId, UlId)
{
    console.log(MembroIdInputId);
    $("#" + MembroIdInputId).val(Id);
    $("#" + ProdNomeInputId).val(Name);
    
    // remove a lista buscada apos selecionar o item
    $("#" + UlId + " li").remove();
    
    // esconde o bloco do resultado da busca
    $(".yui-ac-content").hide();
    $(".yui-ac-hd").hide();
}

function bind()
{
    $('.membro_autocomplete').unbind('keyup').keyup(function(){ 
 $inputMembro = $(this).closest('input');
 $inputMembroId = $(this).closest('td').find("input[class='membro_id']"); 
 $divResultados = $(this).closest('td').find("input[class='yui-ac-container']"); 
  
 autoCompleteMembro($inputMembro, $inputMembroId, $divResultados);
    }); 
}
bind();

function addJson(campo, texto){
   jsonResultado.push({
      guia: campo,
      texto: texto
   });
}

function sendToPhp()
{

   jsonResultado = [];
  
   var validado = true;
   
   var linha_class = ".conteudo";
   var linhasTabela = $(linha_class);
   var num_linhas = linhasTabela.length;
   
   linhasTabela.each(function(){
      var campos = $(this).find("input[type=text]");
      var num_campos = campos.length;
      
      campos.each(function(i,e){
         linha_idx = $(e).closest(linha_class).index(linha_class);

         if($(this).val() == "" && i == 0){
            alert("Primeira coluna não pode ter campo vazio!");
            validado = false;
         }else{
            var guia =
            i == 0 ? "membro" :
            i == 1 ? "dizimo" :
            i == 2 ? "oferta" :
            i == 3 ? "oferta_especial" :
            i == 4 ? "missoes" :
            i == 5 ? "cesta_basica" :
            i == 6 ? "ana_nazareno" :
            i == 7 ? "outros" : null;
            addJson(guia, $(this).val());
         }
      });
      
   });
   
   if(validado){
      alert("Formulário está ok!");
      jsonResultado = JSON.stringify(jsonResultado);
   }
   
}

function check()
{
    var ok = 1;
    $('#Membro0').blur(function()
        {
            if($(this).val().length === 0)
            { 
                ok = 0; $(this).css('border-color','red');
                alert('Campo MEMBRO deve ser preenchido');
            }
    else{ $(this).css('border-color',''); }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="EditView_tabs"> 
    <div>
        <div id="detailpanel_1" class="edit view edit508  expanded">            
            
            <form id="formRelatorio" method="POST" action="index.php?module=culto_relatorio_dizimo&action=gravaRelatorio">
                <input type="hidden" name="module" value="culto_relatorio_dizimo">
                <input type="hidden" name="record" value="">
                <input type="hidden" id="action" name="gravaRelatorio">
                <input type="hidden" name="return_module" value="culto_relatorio_dizimo">
                <input type="hidden" name="return_action" value="relatorioDizimo">
                
                <table id="tabela"  width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" class="yui3-skin-sam edit view panelContainer">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="larg">Membro</th>
                        <th class="larg">Dizimo</th>
                        <th class="larg">Oferta</th>
                        <th class="larg">Oferta Especial</th>
                        <th class="larg">Missões</th>
                        <th class="larg">Cesta Básica</th>
                        <th class="larg">ANA Nazareno</th>
                        <th class="larg">Outros</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class='conteudo'>
                        
                        <td class="tabe"> 
                           <input id="membro_id0" class="membro_id" type="hidden" value="">
                           <input id="Membro0" class="larg membro_autocomplete" type="text">                            
                           <div id="EditView_Membro_results0" class="yui-ac-container">
                               <div class="yui-ac-content" style="display: none;">
                                   <div class="yui-ac-hd" style="display: none;">
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="yui-ac-bd">
                                       <ul id="UserAutoCompleteContent0" style="z-index: 100;" class='list-data'> </ul>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="yui-ac-ft" style="display: none;">
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="tabe"> 
                            <input id="dizimo_id0" class="dizimo_id" type="hidden" value="">
                            <input id="Dizimo0" class="larg dizimo_autocomplete" type="text"> 
                            <div id="EditView_Dizimo_results0" class="yui-ac-container">
                              
                           </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="tabe"> 
                            <input id="oferta_id0" class="oferta_id" type="hidden" value="">
                            <input id="Oferta0" class="larg oferta_autocomplete" type="text"> 
                            <div id="EditView_Oferta_results0" class="yui-ac-container">
                              
                           </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="tabe"> 
                            <input id="oferta_especial_id0" class="oferta_especial_id" type="hidden" value="">
                            <input id="OfertaEspecial0" class="larg oferta_especial_autocomplete" type="text"> 
                            <div id="EditView_OfertaEspecial_results0" class="yui-ac-container">
                              
                           </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="tabe"> 
                            <input id="missoes_id0" class="missoes_id" type="hidden" value="">
                            <input id="Missoes0" class="larg missoes_autocomplete" type="text"> 
                            <div id="EditView_Missoes_results0" class="yui-ac-container">
                              
                           </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="tabe"> 
                            <input id="cesta_basica_id0" class="cesta_basica_id" type="hidden" value="">
                            <input id="CestaBasica0" class="larg cesta_basica_autocomplete" type="text"> 
                            <div id="EditView_CestaBasica_results0" class="yui-ac-container">
                              
                           </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="tabe"> 
                            <input id="ana_nazareno_id0" class="ana_nazareno_id" type="hidden" value="">
                            <input id="AnaNazareno0" class="larg ana_nazareno_autocomplete" type="text"> 
                            <div id="EditView_AnaNazareno_results0" class="yui-ac-container">
                              
                           </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="tabe"> 
                            <input id="outros_id0" class="outros_id" type="hidden" value="">
                            <input id="Outros0" class="larg outros_autocomplete" type="text"> 
                            <div id="EditView_Outros_results0" class="yui-ac-container">
                              
                           </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td> <button type="button" onclick="addRow(this)">Adicionar</button> </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </form>
            
            <div class="fora">
                <button type="button" class="buton" id="sendBtnEnviar" onclick="sendToPhp()">Inserir</button> 
                <input id="countLine" class="countLine" type="hidden" value="1"> 
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Essa pergunta tem mais de 1 ano e foi abandonada... eu fui fuçar perguntas abandonadas e consegui resolver... como é um caso particular, não achei necessário explicar... a pergunta em si já explica, ou seja, queria apenas ver se o primeiro campo de cada linha está vazio ou não. Não creio que isso seja útil a ninguém no futuro ou no passado rs... se quiser dá downvote por esse detalhe, mesmo a resposta resolvendo o problema, fique à vontade.

Comment: Minha pontaria está ruim, acertei a seta errada :D